# Proper way to clean-up new object array in JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

How should the result of `NewObjectArray` be handled if a failure occurs while partially filling up the new array?

That is, I want to abort the creation. Is it sufficient to delete the local reference to the array? Will this remove the children, as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless it's assigned to a Java field or used as a JNI function return value, the reference will be garbage collected automagically once the native calls returns. It's a local ref - those don't live past the JNI call.

Comment: Ok, that works. I wasn't thinking that its localref is just like any other localref...duh

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question while looking up for the same topic (`jobjectArray` release) and I noticed that the answer provided by @Seva is not complete.

You **can** delete the `jobjectArray LocalRef` just like any other `LocalRef`, using:

```
env->DeleteLocalRef(the_array);
// OR
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, the_array);
```

Of course, as with any other `LocalRef`, you can avoid manual deletion and rely on the GC to do the magic for you but if you need many of them in the same JNI function or, for instance, you're running a loop that allocates new JNI `LocalRef`s and you're not deleting them you're going to have a bad time once they overflow the table limit (which is pretty low, set to 512).

*NOTE*

If you're going to manually delete the array reference you need to remember that `DeleteLocalRef` function on a `jobjectArray` will not release its child elements.

Hence when you're using `jobjectArray` you need to keep track of the elements or loop through all elements and delete them one by one.

The same goes with *primitive* arrays but for these you have the

```
env->Release<Primitive>ArrayElements(the_array, 
           the_elements_to_remove, 
           release_mode);
// OR
(*env)->Release<Primitive>ArrayElements(env, 
           the_array, 
           the_elements_to_remove, 
           release_mode);
```